# Unable to debug in PyCharm because of an ImportError in pydevconsole.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am suddenly getting the following error in PyCharm whenever I try to debug my code. This seems to be happening only when I try to debug a specific project and the error doesn't seem to occur in other projects.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pydevd_breakpoints import * #@UnusedWildImport
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pydevd_comm import GetGlobalDebugger
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 74, in <module>
    import pydevconsole
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 8, in <module>
    from code import compile_command
ImportError: cannot import name compile_command
```

I searched around and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157925/pycharm3-0-1win7-when-i-debug-my-webpy-project-it-output-importerror-cannot-im), but it didn't work for me since I have no additional `code.py` in my project.

UPDATE:

I created a new project in PyCharm and moved the files the files to the new project and was able to debug..

Comment: You need to check also for a package named `code`, not just a `code.py` file.

Comment: @yole don't have any package named `code` in my repository nor in the External Package.

Comment: Just for reference. I managed to fix it after finding this question and realizing that calling a module `code` is not the best thing as IntelliJ has its own module called like that.

Comment: My file was named code.py. When I renamed it to something else, it worked!

Answer (score 18):

A directory called 'code' that had somehow acquired an empty `__init__.py` file caused this for me. I suppose that's technically a module!

Edit: This happened again. Pycharm itself is creating these `__init__.py` files. I haven't found out what's triggering it yet though.

Comment: Calling in from 2019, I can report that PyCharm still has this behavior. Having a python module named `code` makes it impossible to run a Configuration with option "Run with Python Console".

Comment: This even is a problem if the module is in a different (open) project in the project view, as long as that project is checked as a dependency in settings -> project -> project dependencies

Comment: Checking in from the distant year of 2023. This is still an issue.

Answer (score 17):

As said before, this was caused by a module named `code` (i.e. a directory named `code` with a `__init__.py` in it). I renamed it to `src` and it corrected the bug.

Comment: This answer is correct. Having a Python module called code is whats causing the issue. Awesome!

Answer (score 4):

I had same question, because i have a unrelated sub directory where contains file code.py, actually i did not use it as code, i just use it as data file to do some word counting test.

Finally, i move the sub directory out of the project.

`...
test_data_file_dir
    ...
    code.py
    ...
...`

It seems pyCharm will load all .py files of the project no matter of how i use them.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the empty **init**.py file, from my directory and reran the debugger in PyCharm. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We added env setting DISABLE_DEBUGPY, wo we do not import debugpy when using PyCharm.